# Hibernate orphan removal logging

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, slf4j

I am trying to log every change of an entity in my app (**delete**, **update**), which I do in the service layer.

**Example:**

I have entity Company which has list of employees inside with orphan **removal = true**.
When I delete the company - app logs "Company XX removed" - company is removed as well as its employees.

The problem is that I miss log like **Company XX removed** and "**Employee XX removed**" or **Employees [XX, YY, AA] removed** because they were removed by hibernate itself, not by explicit call from my app.

Is there any way by which I could set logging for the entities removed via orphan removal?

Comment: If you have the `Company` instance at hand, you probably also have a list of the employees as field in the company. Use that as I'd guess all employees are removed

Answer (score 1):

What you need is **Hibernate even listeners**. You should implement listeners for **update** and **delete** operations. It will allow you to **log all changes automatically** and regardless of the reason (even if it's caused by orphan removal).

Given the scenarios you've described, I would suggest doing that regardless of these issues with orphan removal.

You have a couple of options:

1. Manually implement listeners. Please see the related post [How to replicate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723204/how-to-replicate-insert-update-delete-statements-using-jpa-and-hibernate)
2. Use callback annotations `@PostUpdate` and `@PostDelete`. See Hibernate doc [Example of specifying JPA callbacks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks)